# Location of global phonebook

Tags: windows, vpn

I have question where can i find global phone book in windows 10.

When you create VPN connection with powershell or windows settings it will be saved into:

%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk

Problem is when i use parameter -AllUserConnection for creating VPN so other users can use the connection from login screen too it will be saved into global phonebook due to msdocs.

It's not same phonebook in location above, cause i can see VPN connection in my network adapters but its not store in the phonebook and without that parameter it will stored in that phonebook.

Any ideas where this global phonebook is stored?

Need it for my automatization script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer.

Global phonebook is in here:

```
    C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here as related and may help any other people with similar issue.

Basically I had an issue where I was creating a VPN connection using a Powershell script and executing that script using Meraki System's Manager.  I managed to somehow cause the 'Get-VPNConnection' cmd to just hang!

Anyway I thought it would add it to global phonebook in C:\ProgramData\ but it in fact added it to this location:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk
```